# Implementing semantic searching with RDF

Tags: java, search, rdf, sparql

I'm trying to create a semantic search using Java as a base programming language.

My task is to create a search prototype which contains triples namely patients, visits and doctors. If i search with a patient name the result should be the patients name and the the time of visit and the corresponding doctors name.

I'm going to use triples in the form of text files say patients, visits and doctors information will be contained in each text file for e.g. patient.txt, visits.txt and doctors.txt respectively.

Here I'm going to create the search using java along with some integrity constraints to fetch the results which I'm sure I would be able to do it. But i had been asked to do this using RDF concepts. This is where the confusion starts, I'm not really sure how to integrate RDF concepts and triples with java and I'm also not really where to start it.

Answer (score 4):

Jena http://jena.sourceforge.net/ is a good API to start a semantic web application with JAVA.
 Build your file using a RDF or a N3 syntax.
You can store your data in a mysql-based database (RDF-store) and query it with the SPARQL language.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some of the APIs that provide RDF support for Java. You can check those out and decide which one will work best for you.

1. [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/)
2. [JRDF](http://jrdf.sourceforge.net/)
3. [Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org)

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/edu/x-dw-x-sparql.html?S_TACT=105AGX01&S_CMP=HP) is a general introduction to SPARQL query development using Jena and Joseki.